# T-SQL equivalent to Python Pandas Concatenate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, union

I have a few tables that I would like to merge in a similar way that [Python Pandas Concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) does.  I do not want to replicate the information for it is rather large. I'd like to have a `VIEW` like behavior.  Let me illustrate by a fake example that as far as I know would not work but just to properly explain what I would like to achieve.

Let us say I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    [a] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [b] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [c] [varchar] (32) NULL,
    [d] [bigint] NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    [a] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [b] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [c] [varchar] (32) NULL,
    [e] [varchar](256) NULL,
)
GO
```

Where `a, b, c` are equivalent but hold different data.  `d` exists in `table_1` but not in `table_2` and `e` exists in `table_2` but not in `table_1`.

Tables do not hold any common data. That is, a `JOIN` on any field would bring zero results.

I would like to be able to do the following (Or something equivalent rather. I know what I am showing is not doable):

```
CREATE VIEW MyUnion FROM(
SELECT * FROM table_1 UNION SELECT * FROM table_2) AS alldata;
```

In such a way that if I run:

```
SELECT * FROM MyUnion;
```

And would get something like (`1` and `One` are just filler representing a generic number or string):

```
a       b       c       d       e
1       1       One     1       NULL
1       1       One     NULL    One
```

Is there any way to do anything like this without duplicating the data? (i.e. creating another table holding everything)

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?:

```
CREATE VIEW MyUnion AS
SELECT
    a, b, c,
    d,
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(32)) AS e 
FROM table_1 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    a, b, c, 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS d,
    e
FROM table_2 ;
```